# What is $E$ with respect to the relation between an electric field and its polarization density?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

To avoid confusion let:-

$E_0$ be electric field we applied, $E_p$ be electric field caused by polarization and $E_n$ be net electric field i.e. $E_n = E_0 - E_p$

In the relation
$P=\epsilon_o\chi_eE$  which E is used?

Comment: what would happen if it's $E_p$?

Comment: I don't think it is $E_p$, because then how can I  deriving the result $K=1+\chi_e$?

Comment: $E$ is the electric field at equilibrium, that is, $E_n$.

Comment: @Jono94 but if polarization($P$) is increased, which means more dipoles are formed so  $E_p$ will increase and $E_n$ must reduce, right?

Comment: To increase polarisation, we will first need to increase the applied field $E_0$, and get a response $E_p$ that won’t be as strong, resulting in a net increase in $E_n$. The best thing about linear dielectrics is that $P$ happens to be proportional to $E_n$.

Comment: @Jono94 oh I see. I was confused whether $E_n$ is directly proportional to $P$. Can you write it as answer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\mathbf{E}$ in the formula is the electric field at equilibrium $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{total}$ (In the following answer I shall use $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{total}$ in place of $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{n}$).

What happens when we apply an external field $\mathbf{E}_0$ is that the material become polarised, and produces a polarisation field $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{p},1}$ whose direction is opposite that of the applied field. This field contributes to the total field, which in turn modifies the polarisation to produce another polarisation field $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{p},2}$ ... until the process ends at some combination of $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{total}$ and $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{p}$ such that $\mathbf{P} = \epsilon_0\chi_\mathrm{e}\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{total}$.

To increase the polarisation, we will first need to increase the applied field $\mathbf{E}_0$, and get a response $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{p}$ that won’t be as strong, resulting in a net increase in $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{total}$. The best thing about linear dielectrics is that $\mathbf{P}$ happens to be proportional to $\mathbf{E}_\mathrm{total}$.

---

As a sidenote, the relation $\mathrm{\mathbf{P}} = \epsilon_0\chi_\mathrm{e} \mathrm{\mathbf{E}} $ is only true for a **homogeneous isotropic linear dielectric** (which for the sake of brevity is usually referred to as a **linear dielectric**), when the external field is not too strong. The general form of polarisation $\mathrm{\mathbf{P}}$ is
$$ \frac{P_i}{\epsilon_0} = \chi^{(1)}_{ij}E_j \; + \chi^{(2)}_{ijk}E_jE_k\;+\chi^{(3)}_{ijkl}E_jE_kE_k\;+ \;\cdots\;, $$
where the Einstein summing convention is used, $\chi^{(1)}$ is the **linear susceptibility**, $\chi^{(2)}$ is the second-order susceptibility tensor, $\chi^{(3)}$ is the third-order susceptibility tensor and so on.